# Jenkins Artifactory plug-in: Error occurred while requesting version information: Connection refused

Tags: jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I get the error "Error occurred while requesting version information: Connection refused" when I test the connection in Jenkins configuration for Artifactory plug-in. I have tried it with Anonymous access enabled in Artifactory, with Anonymous access disabled, and tried all three options (Supported, Unsupported, Required) for Password Encryption in Artifactory. I have Default Deployer Credentials in my Jenkins Artifactory configuration, and I have tested the connection with 'Use Different Resolver Credentials' and without. I consistently get this error.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, Did you the solution for this?. I also have same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I also ran in a similar problem yesterday.

**Problem:**
I was running jenkins and artifactory in two different docker containers on my local. I had exposed port `8086` for artifactory and could access it using `http://localhost:8086/artifactory` in my browser. But giving the same url for artifactory in jenkins produced the above reported error in question.

**Solution:**
For some unknown reasons, jenkins artifactory plugin couldn't resolve `http://localhost:8086/artifactory` even though the docker mappings was correct and it was possible to connect to artifactory web based console with the same URL.

Replacing "localhost" with docker container IP did the trick.
Name of my container in which artifactory was running was `docker-plgr_artifactory_1`

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ prakash.tiwari$ docker exec -it docker-plgr_artifactory_1 cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.2  08038bc9449b
```

The IP of container was `172.18.0.2`. So I replaced `http://localhost:8086/artifactory` with `http://172.18.0.2:8081/artifactory` and jenkins was now able to connect to artifactory. (`8081` is the port in docker container at which artifactory was running. You'd have given it at the time of running the container. Alternatively, you can find it by running `docker ps` and checking the value under `PORTS` field.)

**Credit**: https://www.arvinep.com/2016/04/jenkins-docker-container-problem.html

**Note:** I know this solution doesn't explain the cause and why it works, but I hope it at least helps some people and saves their time.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you asked this question a while ago. I just had to deal with a very similar situation. I had loaded the root and intermediate certificates into the cacerts files found under the 4 version of Java on the build server. The problem was that Jenkins uses it's own cacerts file found in the Jenkins install folder. Once I loaded the certs there I was able to test the connection to artifactory and upload the build artifacts. I hope this helps